TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tupl
This is a common question on SO but all the examples I've looked at are fairly complicated. So I am posting the simplest example I can think of to get a straight-forward answer.
x = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
print(x[0])
  (1,2)
print(x[0,1])
  TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

The error message indicates that if I want a consecutive range of elements, I can use a slice: x[0:2]. But what if I want non-consecutive elements like x[0,2]? How do I get those by index?

print([x[i] for i in [0,1]])

Refer to the elements separately, just as you would when printing any two values.  print(x[0], x[2])

you should use [] twice: print(x[0][1])

Check out How to ask a good question for tips, like how to write a good title and including what research you've done. I assume you haven't seen the linked question since it covers your question perfectly. I just had to google "python get non consecutive elements in a list" to find it.

Using pure python you could use a list comprehension
def get_values(data, indices):
  return [data[i] for i in indices]

For example
>>> x = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> get_values(x, [0, 2])
[(1, 2), (5, 6)]

Using numpy you could directly use another array to index
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)])
>>> arr[np.array([0,2])]
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])

